# Как исправить ошибку в VS2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp

Ошибка вылезает при попытке добавления SplitView в UWP C#.

Делал Repair VS, не помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/daa9a39d-5d2b-4b9d-9d76-a4face81d127/uwp-splitview-problem-on-windows-10-after-applying-update-1?forum=wpdevelop) и [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045807/uwp-splitview-issue-after-installing-visual-studio-2015-1). Наиболее вероятно, что Вам придётся отказаться от использования дизайнера в MSVS, пока этот баг не будет исправлен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такую же ошибку ловил. Добавлял сплит прописыванием `<SplitView />` в XAML разметке. После этого с элементом можно работать и в дизайнере.